# calculate mean of certain arrays inside the large array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How the mean of every three arrays inside the big array can be calculated?

```
my_array = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]]

numpy_array = np.array(my_array)
mean_each_array= [np.mean (x) for x in numpy_array]
result_mean_each_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #OK
mean_every_three_arrays = ???
result_mean_every_three_arrays = [2,5] how? 
"I want to calculate mean of [1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3] and [4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]"
```

Comment: Suppose `my_array` to be list of rows which is a list of columns. Do you want to calculate mean of the columns separately? e.g. mean(1,2,3,4,5,6)?

Comment: in your supposition, i want to calculate mean of every three columns separately @Ashish Nitin Patil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]])

reshaped = my_array.reshape(2, -1)    
result = np.mean(reshaped, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> reshaped
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
>>> result
array([ 2.,  5.])
```

As a side note, you don't need to loop over an array get a mean for each row:

```
>>> np.mean(my_array, axis=1) # gives you a mean for each row
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
>>> np.mean(my_array, axis=0) # gives you a mean for each column
array([ 3.5,  3.5,  3.5])
```

Comment: thanks, accepted and upvoted! can you tell me meaning of -1 in reshaped = my_array.reshape(2, -1) @Akavall

Comment: `my_array` has 18 values, that means that if I specify that I want two rows, then `reshape` function knows that I want 9 columns, basically `reshaped = my_array.reshape(2, -1)` is the same as `reshaped = my_array.reshape(2, 9)`.

Answer (score 1):

I got idea - Reshaping the array!

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]])
new_array = my_array.reshape(9, 2)
result= [np.mean (x) for x in new_array]
print (result)
[2.0, 5.0]
```